# Wireless network router and coordinator

Tags: embedded, wifi, xbee

I have two `XBee`s and cannot get what it means to set up one of the XBees as `AT coordinator` and the other one as `AT router`. Can you please explain me what is the difference?  What does the router do and what does the coordinator do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinator establishes the network, and multiple routers can join that network.  If you're familiar with TCP/IP networks, think of the coordinator as a DHCP server, and routers as DHCP clients.

Comment: Thank you. What does the AT in coordinator AT stand for?

Comment: It stands for "attention", and references the "AT commands" (also referred to as the [Hayes Command Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)) used to control modems.

Comment: I cannot get what are the caracteristics of the AT mode? What is the difference between the AT and API mode?

Comment: AT mode is sometimes called "transparent serial" because it simply relays data to/from the serial port of one XBee radio to another.  In order to control the local XBee, the host sends an escape sequence ("+++", with a 1 second pause before and after) to enter command mode where it can send "AT commands".  In API mode, both host and XBee communicate with framed packets.  In general, it's more difficult for a host to use API mode, but it's more capable and ultimately easier if your needs extend past a "transparent serial" device.